# Android Emulator Hanging

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just updated my Android SDK installation with Lollipop and the corresponding ARMv7 image. However when I try to start the emulator, it hangs at the black screen with the flashing Android logo. I have tried this many times with the option to use host GPU on and off.
My emulator settings are: 
Ram - 768MB
Internal storage - 4GB
SD - 1GB

Other images I've installed work OK. This is really frustrating; I am so eager to check out the new features.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Oh, and heap is 128MB

Comment: Deleting the AVD & creating a new one doesn't solve the problem.